# I need help getting my sub-query to work? I would like to know if it is faster using a sub-query then my foreach loop way?

Tags: php

// I will be transferring data from one table to another for a frontend-app, which will involove many tables. Time matters here. Original way I would repopulate one table to another
and my DB class works, it is not the problem so no need to put it up here. Thank you for help

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM staging_flows";
$RES = $db->query($SQL);
```

// looping thruogh the results of my query into staging_flows table

```
foreach($RES as $row){
  $id = $row['id'];
  $flow_name = $row['flow_name'];
  $coops = $row['coops'];
  $changed_flag = $row['changed_flag'];
  $removed_flag = $row['removed_flag'];
```

// Updating the flows table with the data collected from staging_flows table

```
$SQL1 = "UPDATE flows SET flow_name='$flow_name', coops='$coops', 
changed_flag='$changed_flag', removed_flag='$removed_flag' WHERE id='$id'";
$RES = $db->query($SQL1);
```

//I have been trying a truncate function I developed and the use of sub-query but I
can't get it to sub-query to work. I think the performTruncateTable() function is
sounds.

// Function for Truncate Table

```
function performTruncateTable($table_name){
  $db = new Db();
  $link  = $db->connect();
  $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE `" . $table_name . "`";
  $query_response = $db->query($query);
  return $query_response;
}
function performTruncateTable_DB($db,$table_name){
  $link  = $db->connect();
  $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE `" . $table_name . "`";
  $query_response = $db->query($query);
  return $query_response;
}
```

// Truncate flows table

```
performTruncateTable_DB($db,'flows')
```

// Populate flows table with data from the staging flows table using a sub-query

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO flows (id,flow_name,coops) SELECT (id,flow_name,coops) FROM 
staging_flows";
$res2 = $db->query($sql2);
```

Comment: What sub-query are you talking about? ... I don't see any sub-query in the examples. Also, what is the point of `$link =` in the functions? ... the reference is not used.

Comment: The sub-query at the end to populate my flows table from my stagin-flows table: $sql2 = "INSERT INTO flows (id,flow_name,coops) SELECT (id,flow_name,coops) FROM 
staging_flows";

Comment: Oh, I see, I don't call that a subquey when part of an `insert ... select` query, but I see how it could be considered to be one.